# Typescript changes type inference of return value depending on if there is a variable

Tags: typescript

I am confused by the below code:

```js
type TestSymbol = 'a' | 'b';
type TestType = { test: TestSymbol }

function test1(): TestType {  // no error
  return { test: 'a' };
}

function test2(): TestType {  // tsserver error 2322
  const x = { test: 'a' };
  return x;
}
```

The error message is:

```
Type '{ test: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TestType'.
  Types of property 'test' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TestSymbol'.
[tsserver: 2322]
```

It appears typescript is classifying the `test` property of the return object differently in `test1` and `test2`. In `test1`, it understands that the `'a'` value is a `TestSymbol`. But in `test2`, it only classifies it as a string, causing the type error.

Why does it do this and how can I help typescript understand that `test` is a `TestSymbol` in `test2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is no explicit [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) on a variable or other expression, the TypeScript compiler will [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) its type based on some heuristic rules that are a reasonable guess as to the intended type.  These rules are not perfect, but they are useful.

In your first example,

```
function test1(): TestType {  
  return { test: 'a' };
}
```

the compiler infers the type of `{test: 'a'}` to be `TestType` [*contextually*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by the return type of the function.  Contextual type inference means that the compiler infers the type of an expression based on what type is expected to be there.  This only happens in specific circumstances, and cannot occur if a type has already been inferred for a value.

For example, when you declare a variable like:

```
const x = { test: 'a' };
```

the compiler immediately infers the type of `x` based on the value `{test: 'a'}`.  It does not wait until it sees `x` used somewhere to figure out what the best type would be.  The inferred type is `{test: string}`.  Even though `x` is a `const`, the property `x.test` can be changed, so the compiler assumes that `x.test` can be any `string`.  Often such assumptions are correct, but in your case it is not.

---

To fix this, you can either explicitly annotate the type of `x`:

```
function testAnnotation(): TestType {
  const x: TestType = { test: 'a' }; // <-- explicit annotation
  return x; // okay
}
```

or you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to change the inference heuristic so that the compiler assumes that nothing about `x` will change:

```
function testConstAssertion(): TestType {
  const x = { test: 'a' } as const; // <-- ask for narrowest possible type
  // const x: { readonly test: "a"; } 
  return x; // okay
}
```

The inferred type for `x` is now `{ readonly test: "a"; }`; the compiler assumes that the `test` property will never change and that its only possible value is `"a"`.  This is seen as assignable to `TestType` (the fact that `readonly` properties are assignable to non-`readonly` properties is a little weird, but it's intended behavior and you can read a suggestion to change this at [microsoft/TypeScript#13347](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347)) and there is no compiler error.

Either way should work.

---

Note that I would not recommend using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) of the form:

```
function testLessSafeTypeAssertion(): TestType {
  const x = { test: 'a' } as TestType;
  return x;
}
```

While this will compile, it is less safe, because you are just *telling* the compiler that `{test: "a"}` is a `TestType` instead of asking the compiler to verify it.  Type assertions tend to miss certain errors:

```
const x = { test: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'a' : 'z' } as TestType; // no error!
```

where type annotations catch them:

```
const x: TestType = { test: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'a' : 'z' }; // error
```

Type assertions are useful primarily in situations where the compiler *cannot* verify the type of a value, and you need to give the compiler the information it doesn't have.  In this case the compiler can check that `x` is a `TestType` on its own, so an annotation or a `const` assertion is safer.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDKIC2AjA9gGygXigHIBDQqAHyPUIG4AoUSWBYGcaAgbymBYC5miFBhxQAvnToAzAK4A7AMbAAlpjk8WARgAUASgFxEbJtygB6M1DmYoEAE53MdulCh2IwGXfXdeiASRkYvQS0vJKqup+wACCctbAxCpqegYsxtCcLlAKaohQAB5pRuz4UL78RKTiNOaWADwAtI22BWDYygrKwFDE8ZiJyXLZ7p7ehbUWUJgA1sQgdKGyikMaiADCebHw8PZDqYKspVmuuXL5BWUV-lVBvfA5W5MNzfczUFJOVsQOmADuLCgYEwO2U6Gw0EYEGyUzOFwE3HcxAAJmpsCA1sABAAiYjY2piKAjDxedQFEKSMIrSKYgAyCHgSGIUggGRiOz2kQOhiOJmycJ6ly4mIC1UJxAePIy9Fco1JE0WkgFUAxwuiAgAskkABYAOjsfVRqD0UHqUAADLqAKxQAD8tygAQAXncJYdpXUrDZ7I47ABCOjKp3FXkccoiqBa4B6g1yI0ms2Wm32wKOogumqen1OOhAA)

Answer (score 2):

Because in `test1`, the object is directly returned and type is inferred based on the return type of the function. You can manually assert the type when using a variable so you don't rely on type inference:

```
function test2(): TestType {
  const x = { test: 'a' } as TestType;
  return x;
}
```

Or explicitly annotate the type of variable:

```
function test2(): TestType {
  const x: TestType = { test: 'a' };
  return x;
}
```

[plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#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-XyiUAJjNFqt1JtKlQgkEPz0OJ+TtAkYAzJHIy70ZwJaBVrGJVK2V6FRyuerha7IO6vKtA5rtWGDRLszGldaCwgizQwZWI6hfbW1WJhJbyy166A3YTm62VDgGh4PaBEPABgwQewaN83GZmOwGMxIPxYNB1Ik9-A9CIvAAiACiqwYiBq+mfSRxz-ABxUHZYQADlIAkZ8ghUAB5b4yF2FN+AvY5UEcBRXGkPAF0gbcdFGLB9BQBBEBhYQriPCQd2iEQDA4HFuhYNguG4IISiAA)

Comment: The main problem is that typescript will consider ‘a’ to be a string and then not consider it’s value in the type inference, so it won’t match.

Comment: The term "cast" is ambiguous and best avoided in TypeScript. Instead of "casted based on the return type" you might say "[contextually typed](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by the return type".  And when you say "manually cast", your first example is a [type assertion](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (which is what people usually call a "cast" in TS), while your second example is actually a [type annotation](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables).

Comment: @jcalz Good point. Definitely type assertion in typescript is a bit different than what cast means in other languages.